# Is it possible to play music streams on iOs devices

Tags: ios, itunes

On My macbook iTunes I have an internet tab which has about 4000 music channels in total. Is it possible to play those in iOS device iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possibilities. For example, you can stream directly to the device from the network.. [Here is an article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1168142/three_apps_for_listening_to_streaming_radio_on_your_ios_device.html) gauging three of these. It's a little dated, but you will get the idea. To stream directly from the macbook to your iOS device, you may be able to use [Airplay](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4437?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). I think it depends on what specific computer and operating system you are using.

If these answers are dead ends, let me know and I can look some more. Please provide more system info, to help myself, and others make suggestions.

Comment: I initially wanted to use siri to play some jazz music on my iPad. So I would prefer siri controllable apps.

Comment: Are you using the new iOS 8? see this page: https://www.apple.com/ios/siri/

Comment: Yes I am using the latest iOS 8.

I said to Siri 'Play some Jazz'. Then she replied 'you do not have any jazz in your music library'. So I thought that I should put the 4000 musci channels from my macbooks iTunes  somehow into my iOS 8 iTunes... but that didn't work... So I can't instruct Siri to play any jazz without buying some jazz...

Comment: Have you tried "Play some Jazz Radio"? I just tried and it seems ok to me :)

Comment: For doing that I need to reregister with another apple id which points to a USA store. Unfortunatelly the iTunes radio doesn't work here in romania... :(

Comment: My son (who lives in Bucharest) says there is an AppleStore presence in Romania, that he uses for internet radio. But he also acknowledges that it is small compared to other stores.